# How to know the creation time of a file by PHP?

Tags: php

Is there any way to get the time when file was created by PHP ?

The manual says that `filectime()` can not do that ?

Is there any way ?

Comment: Read the PHP manual, more specifically the section on file manipulation/information functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`filectime()` will do it but if you are using windows you can get creation time `but if you are using UNIX you can get the change time and that would be all.`

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, you can get "File Creation Date" by:
Example:

```
<?php
    echo filemtime("test.txt");
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Last modified: ".date("F d Y H:i:s.",filemtime("test.txt"));
?>
```

You will get this type of output:

```
11388197
Last modified: February 01 2006 18:49:37.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this example
On windows the CTime is the creation time, use the following:

```
<?php
$files = array();

foreach (new DirectoryIterator('/path') as $fileInfo) {    
    $files[$fileInfo->getFileName()] = $fileInfo->getCTime();
}

arsort($files);
```

This will give you the creation time of file by php